# SQL query for first record when a flag is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

please consider below table

```
Flag        Date
-----        -------
N           01/01/2017
N           03/01/2017 
N           04/01/2017
Y           06/01/2017
Y           09/01/2017 
N           12/01/2017
N           14/01/2017
Y           15/01/2017
Y           16/01/2017
Y           19/01/2017
N           23/01/2017
```

what is the SQL code to get below result

```
Flag1           Date1         Flag2       Date2
--------      ----------     ---------     ----------
Y              06/01/2017       N          12/01/2017
Y              15/01/2017       N          23/01/2017
```

Thanks.

Comment: please write a comment at least why you downvoted!

Comment: What is the actual requirement. I could not understand? You want Y and N in different columns or anything else?

Comment: Something like this is probably what you're looking for: `SELECT Flag1 = 'Y', Date1 = MIN(T.[Date]), Flag2 = 'N', Date2 = C.[Date] FROM myTable T CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN([Date]) FROM myTable WHERE Flag ='N' AND [Date] >= T.[Date]) C([Date]) WHERE T.Flag = 'Y' GROUP BY C.[Date];`

Comment: there is 1 to n number of records which their flag field is N then this is followed by 0 to n number of records which their flag field is Y. this pattern can be repeated any number of times . I want to get first Y records and for each of them I want to get first record which its flag is N and appears after the group of records which their flag value is Y. I have tried to show this with my example. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will help you assume that you use `SQL Server 2012` or newer (which support `LEAD` and `LAG`). Change `date_column` to name of your date column

```
SELECT flag1, date1, flag2, date2
FROM
(
    SELECT flag flag1,
        date_column date1,
        LEAD(flag) OVER (ORDER BY date_column) flag2,
        LEAD(date_column) OVER (ORDER BY date_column) date2
    FROM 
    (   
        SELECT flag, date_column,
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(LAG(flag) OVER (ORDER BY date_column), 'NULL') <> flag THEN 1 ELSE 0 END search_col
        FROM table_name
    ) t
    WHERE search_col = 1
)
WHERE flag1 = 'Y';
```

You could run each subquery to know the logic of the query.

And finally, in your comment you said `there is 1 to n number of records which their flag field is N then this is followed by 0 to n number of records which their flag field is Y.` In the case 3N then 0Y then 4N, how could you know it is not 7N, not 2N then 0Y then 5N,.... ? And what is desired result in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (FLAG CHAR(10),DATE CHAR(20),ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','01/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','03/01/2017'); 
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','04/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Y','06/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Y','09/01/2017'); 
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','12/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','14/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Y','15/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Y','16/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Y','19/01/2017');
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('N','23/01/2017');

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (FLAG CHAR(10),DATE CHAR(20),ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) )
DECLARE @T3 TABLE (FLAG CHAR(10),DATE CHAR(20),ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))
DECLARE @FLAG CHAR(10),@ID INT,@OLD CHAR(10)

SET @OLD=(SELECT FLAG FROM @T1 WHERE ID=1)

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT FLAG,ID FROM @T1 WHERE ID>1
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FLAG,@ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
IF(@OLD<>@FLAG)
BEGIN
IF @FLAG='Y'
INSERT INTO @T2 SELECT FLAG,DATE FROM @T1 WHERE ID=@ID
ELSE
INSERT INTO @T3 SELECT FLAG,DATE FROM @T1 WHERE ID=@ID
END
SET @OLD=@FLAG
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FLAG,@ID
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
SELECT  A.FLAG,A.DATE,B.FLAG,B.DATE FROM @T2 A INNER JOIN @T3 B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```